# Randomizing Vertex Locations JUNG

Tags: java, graph, jung

I have created a java program of which starts with 1 vertex and from there it adds one vertice and 2 edges per cycle. It uses the Static Layout

```
Layout<Number, Number> staticLayout = new StaticLayout<Number, Number>(g, layout);
vv = new VisualizationViewer<Number, Number>(staticLayout, new Dimension(550, 550));
```

This is going to sound very un-technical, but the graph just doesn't look random enough, basically what i mean by this, is that every time it gets run they always seems to cluster a lot all the way around the edges of the graph, while very few get anywhere near the center. My program typically uses 100 generated verties and i will end up with half a dozen in the center and the others all round the edges.

Below is a random example that i just created just now.

Perhaps if someone could confirm that this is actually random, or if not if there is a way to get around this problem or if I've set something up wrong. As i wish to have the nodes as random as possible.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

[image: Random Example]

Below is the relevant code to the applet. involving its set up.

```
public class AnimatingAddNodeDemo extends JApplet {

        //create a graph
        Graph<Number, Number> ig = Graphs.synchronizedUndirectedGraph(new UndirectedSparseMultigraph<Number, Number>());

        ObservableGraph<Number, Number> og = new ObservableGraph<Number, Number>(ig);
        og.addGraphEventListener(new GraphEventListener<Number, Number>() {

            public void handleGraphEvent(GraphEvent<Number, Number> evt) {
                //System.err.println("got " + evt);
            }
        });
        this.g = og;
        //create a graphdraw
        layout = new FRLayout<Number, Number>(g);
        layout.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        setSize(700, 700);
        Relaxer relaxer = new VisRunner((IterativeContext) layout);
        relaxer.stop();
        relaxer.prerelax();

        Layout<Number, Number> staticLayout = new StaticLayout<Number, Number>(g, layout);
        vv = new VisualizationViewer<Number, Number>(staticLayout, new Dimension(550, 550));

        JRootPane rp = this.getRootPane();
        rp.putClientProperty("defeatSystemEventQueueCheck", Boolean.TRUE);

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    }

    Integer v_prev = null;

    public void process() {

        vv.getRenderContext().getPickedVertexState().clear();
        vv.getRenderContext().getPickedEdgeState().clear();
        try {
            if (g.getVertexCount() < 100) {
                //add a vertex

                Integer v1 = nodeCount;
                g.addVertex(v1);
                nodeCount++;
                System.out.println("adding vertex " + v1);
                vv.getRenderContext().getPickedVertexState().pick(v1, true);
                j.setText(myText);

                // wire it to some edges
                if (v_prev != null) {
                    Integer edge = edgeCount;
                    //vv.getRenderContext().getPickedEdgeState().pick(edge, true);

                    // let's connect to a random vertex, too!

                    int rand = (int) (Math.random() * (edgeCount-1)); // because there is a 0 node
                    while (v1.equals(rand)) {
                        System.out.println("avoided connecting to myself");
                        rand = (int) (Math.random() * (edgeCount-1)); // because there is a 0 node
                    }

                    edgeCount++;
                    g.addEdge(edge, rand, v1);  //add an edge called var1, between the nodes var2 and var3
                    vv.getRenderContext().getPickedEdgeState().pick(edge, true);
                    System.out.println("Adding edge " + edge + " between " + rand + " & " + v1 + "()");
                }

                v_prev = v1;
                layout.initialize();

                Relaxer relaxer = new VisRunner((IterativeContext) layout);
                relaxer.stop();
                relaxer.prerelax();
                vv.getRenderContext().getMultiLayerTransformer().setToIdentity();
                vv.repaint();

            } else {
                done = true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnimatingAddNodeDemo and = new AnimatingAddNodeDemo();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(and);

        and.init();
        and.start();
        frame.pack();
        //frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm taking a shot in the dark, but it seems like you are passing your `StaticLayout` an `FRLayout` (Fruchterman-Reingold). Your screenshot is how most `FRLayout`s look when their size is too small. The nodes butt against the walls of the layout. I'm guessing JUNG uses the `FRLayout` as a transformer within the `StaticLayout` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your graph isn't random likely stems from the fact that you are passing a `FRLayout` to the constructor.

```
layout = new FRLayout<Number, Number>(g);
// ...
Layout<Number, Number> staticLayout = new StaticLayout<Number, Number>(g, layout);
```

You could make your own random layout class by extending `AbstractLayout`. But, according to the [JavaDoc](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/layout/StaticLayout.html), `StaticLayout` will randomly layout nodes if you exclude the second constructor argument.

```
Layout<Number, Number> staticLayout = new StaticLayout(Number, Number>(g);
```

Comment: I ended up changing layout to static i.e. layout = new StaticLayout<Number, Number>(g) instead of removing the second constructor argument, but this helped a lot thanks.

Comment: @AlexioHill I'm glad it worked. It seems like you did remove the second constructor argument, by simply doing `new StaticLayout<Number, Number>(g)` as opposed to `new StaticLayout<Number, Number>(g, layout)`.

Answer (score 1):

I Didn't get to a conclusion on whether or not it is random. So instead when i create each vertex i decided to set the particular co-ordinate of the vertex using `layout.setLocation(v1, x, y)`
With making x and y using `math.random()` and multiplying it by the width and height of my applet.

Therefore i now know that it is random.

---

**EDIT**

This actually seemed to work, however it actually did not, I had to remove the FRLayout.
It turns out FRLayout will not let you set your own locations because of what the algorithm does.

> FRLayout is a force directed Layout that will reposition the vertices
>   according to the topology of the graph.

So i therefore changed the FRLayout to StaticLayout, removed a few things that worked only with FRLayout and it works correctly now.